# Are equal send() and recv() calls guaranteed with UDP

Tags: udp

When using UDP sockets, is it guaranteed that when A calls send() once, that, provided the buffer is big enough and the packet gets successfully transmitted (without any bit-flips or data loss), the **whole** packet will be read on the other side by B with also exactly one recv() call?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is a UDP packet guaranteed to be complete, practical sense, if delivered?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15954813/is-a-udp-packet-guaranteed-to-be-complete-practical-sense-if-delivered)

Comment: I'm pretty certain the result of UDP packet transmission is "not guaranteed at all" - in other words, your application will need to check everything from size to order and correctness.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Thanks, but that's not the same question. Im well aware of the fact that the packet doesn't need to be "correct", I just want to know if it's guaranteed to come in one "batch".

Comment: @MatsPetersson Not size. UDP datagrams arrive intact or not at all.

Comment: So... apparently this is off topic... okay...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Either a complete datagram arrives or nothing.

Note that reading only part of it will still throw away the rest.

**EDIT:**
More elaborately, when you call `send` on an UDP socket, you send out exactly one datagram (which may be fragmented to several packets and reassembled on underlying protocols such as IP, ethernet, or ATM). This datagram either arrives and passes the checksum, or it doesn't.
If everything went well, you have one complete datagram queued in your receive buffer, which you can `recv` on **exactly once**.

Calling `recv` will copy data from the oldest datagram in the receive buffer up to the limit that you specify (`len` parameter) into your application buffer, *and then discards the datagram*, even if not all of it has been read. The next call to `recv` will read a **different** datagram (the next oldest).

Thus, you really have a strict 1:1 relationship.

Comment: Thanks, will accept in 5 minutes or whatever the time limit is.